# Como eu faço para validar o input radio do meu código?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```js
$(function() {

  $("#btn").click(function() {

    $("#c1").css("background-color", "white");
    $("#c2").css("background-color", "white");
    $("#c3").css("background-color", "white");
    $("#c4").css("background-color", "white");

    /// validação 
    if ($("#c1").val() == "") {
      alert("preencha os campos!!");
      $("#c1").css("background-color", "red");
      return false;

    } else if ($("#c2").val() == "") {
      alert("preencha os campos!!");
      $("#c2").css("background-color", "red");
      return false;

    } else if ($("#c3").val() == "") {
      alert("preencha os campos!!");
      $("#c3").css("background-color", "red");
      return false;
    } else if ($("#c4").val() == "") {
      alert("preencha os campos!!");
      $("#c4").css("background-color", "red");
      return false;
    }

    return true;

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="c1" placeholder="Nome" class="caixa"> <br><br>
<input type="text" id="c2" placeholder="Idade" class="caixa"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="c3" placeholder="Telefone" class="caixa"><br><br>
<input type="password" id="c4" placeholder="Senha" class="caixa"><br><br> M:

<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="masculino" id="r1"><br><br> F:
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="feminino" id="r2"><br><br> Salvar login :<input type="checkbox"><br><br> Menssagem de texto das novidades :<input type="checkbox"><br><br><br>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="entrar">
```

Comment: Cadê o código HTML desses elementos "c"?

Comment: <input type="text" id="c1" placeholder="Nome" class="caixa"> <br><br>
   <input type="text" id="c2" placeholder="Idade" class="caixa" ><br><br>
   <input type="text" id="c3" placeholder="Telefone" class="caixa"><br><br>
   <input type="password" id="c4" placeholder="Senha" class="caixa"><br><br>

Answer (score 2):

Inclua um novo `else if` na validação que verifica se ao menos 1 `radio` foi checado:

```
else if(!$("input[name='sexo']:checked").length){
    alert("Marque M ou F");
    return false;
}
```

### Pequena otimização

Seu código tem algumas coisas repetidas que dá pra otimizar, umas delas são essas linhas:

```
$("#c1").css("background-color", "white");
$("#c2").css("background-color", "white");
$("#c3").css("background-color", "white");
$("#c4").css("background-color", "white");
```

Já que todos os campos possuem a mesma classe `.caixa`, é melhor usar apenas 1 linha pra trocar o background de todos eles:

```
$(".caixa").css("background-color", "white");
```

```js
$(function() {
   $("#btn").click(function() {
      $(".caixa").css("background-color", "white");

      /// validação 
      if ($("#c1").val() == "") {
      alert("preencha os campos!!");
      $("#c1").css("background-color", "red");
      return false;
      } else if ($("#c2").val() == "") {
      alert("preencha os campos!!");
      $("#c2").css("background-color", "red");
      return false;
      } else if ($("#c3").val() == "") {
      alert("preencha os campos!!");
      $("#c3").css("background-color", "red");
      return false;
      } else if ($("#c4").val() == "") {
      alert("preencha os campos!!");
      $("#c4").css("background-color", "red");
      return false;
      } else if(!$("input[name='sexo']:checked").length){
      alert("Marque M ou F");
      return false;
      }

      alert("Formulário validado!");
      return true;
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="c1" placeholder="Nome" class="caixa"> <br><br>
<input type="text" id="c2" placeholder="Idade" class="caixa"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="c3" placeholder="Telefone" class="caixa"><br><br>
<input type="password" id="c4" placeholder="Senha" class="caixa"><br><br> M:
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="masculino" id="r1"><br><br> F:
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="feminino" id="r2"><br><br> Salvar login :<input type="checkbox"><br><br> Menssagem de texto das novidades :<input type="checkbox"><br><br><br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="entrar">
```

Answer (score 1):

Vi que você está utilizando vários if-else para executar exatamente a mesma coisa, como não há variação, resolvi utilizar a função `each`, que recebe uma função como `callback` a ser aplicada em sobre todos os elementos que possuem a classe `caixa`.

Ao invés de realizar um `return` em cada verificação, eu criei uma `flag` iniciando em `true`, se algum campo foi inválido, ela é setada para `false`

```js
$(function() {
   $("#btn").click(function() {
      var valido = true;
      $(".caixa").css("background-color", "white");
      $(".caixa").each(function() {
        if(this.value == "") {
          $(this).css("background-color", "red");
          valido = false;
        }
      });
      
      if(!$("input[name='sexo']:checked").length){
         alert("Marque M ou F");
         valido =  false;
      }
      
      if (valido) {
        alert("Formulário validado!");
        return valido;
      }
      alert("preencha os campos!!");
      return valido;
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="c1" placeholder="Nome" class="caixa"> <br><br>
<input type="text" id="c2" placeholder="Idade" class="caixa"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="c3" placeholder="Telefone" class="caixa"><br><br>
<input type="password" id="c4" placeholder="Senha" class="caixa"><br><br> M:
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="masculino" id="r1"><br><br> F:
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="feminino" id="r2"><br><br> Salvar login :<input type="checkbox"><br><br> Menssagem de texto das novidades :<input type="checkbox"><br><br><br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="entrar">
```

Obs.: Utilizei a resposta do @ÐvÐ como base

Answer (score 1):

Óra, por que simplesmente não utiliza HTML para isto? O único requisito da sua validação é que o campo tenha algum valor (nos de tipo texto) ou que tenha sido selecionado (nos de escolha), isso é facilmente resolvido com o atributo [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) do HTML5:

```html
<form action='/foo' method='post'>
  <label for='male'>Masculino</label>
  <input id='male' type='radio' name='sex' required>
  
  <label for='female'>Feminino</label>
  <input id='female' type='radio' name='sex'>
  
  <button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Talvez faça mais sentido utilizar Javascript para validações complexas, as quais nem mesmo o uso do atributo [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) seja capaz de solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa atribuir o mesmo name para o radio. Como se eles fossem parte do mesmo campo. Depois você acessa o valor utilizando da propriedade ":checked".

Exemplo:

```js
$('input[name=sexo]').on('click', function() {
  var valorDoRadio = $('input[name=sexo]:checked').val();
  alert(valorDoRadio); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="masculino" /> Masculino <br />
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="feminino" /> Femino <br />
```

Com o valor em mãos, você pode validar como quiser.

Comment: Mas porque no click do radio? acho que a intensão é validar quando for enviar o form